# python guessing game not working error_unexpected indent

Tags: python

```
import random

 computerguess=random.randint(0,200)
while True:
   userguess=int(input("enter your number:"))
   if userguess<computerguess:
     print("guess higher")
   elif userguess>computerguess:
     print("guess lower")
   else:
     print("hey!!!! CONGO MAN YOU GOT THE RIGHT NUMBER ")
   break
```

Comment: Put your code into a code tag and use proper indentation for improved readabilty, please.

Comment: Don't use hashtags in the title

Answer (score 1):

The Python interpreter is telling you, thet there are mistakes with the indentation in your code (`Error: Unexpected indent`).

Python uses four spaces (or tabs, but don't mix them) for indentation. Fix every line where you use two instead of four spaces as indentation, the ist should work!